# How to handle promise returning with Mongoose using Bluebird?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bluebird

I have an `Account` schema, defined with Mongoose, I've setup promises with Bluebird:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

I've designed a model method for such schema:

```
accountSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
}
```

So I got a method which will try to find a user and check for password match:

```
function login (email,password) {

    return Account.findOne({email: email}).then(function (user) {
        console.log(user);
        user["match"] = user.validPassword(password);
        console.log(user);
        return user.validPassword(password);
    });
}
```

What's really **weird is that the second `console.log` won't show up any `match` property for the object.**

Here my intention is to *return a promise* of finding a user and check for password match, however when I invoke login:

```
login("email","password").then(function(user){...})
```

User doesn't have a match property, how could I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do both a return prior to invoking the Promise call :   return Account.xxxxx *AND* do a .then()  .... its an either or ...  I give you both alternatives.  Version A we process resultset local to login function :

```
function login (email,password) {

    // notice I no longer have return Account.xxxx
    Account.findOne({email: email}) // Account.findOne returns a Promise
    .then(function (user) {

        if (user) {

            user.match = user.validPassword(password);
            // execute some callback here or return new Promise for follow-on logic

        } else {
            // document not found deal with this
        }

    }).catch(function(err) {

        // handle error
    });
}
```

here the caller does :

```
login("email","password") // needs either a cb or promise
.then(function(userProcessed) { ... 
}).
```

... whereas in Version B we relegate processing to caller to do the .then() logic :

```
function login (email,password) {

    return Account.findOne({email: email});
}
```

so in caller we have :

```
login("email","password").then(function(userNotProcessed){...})
```

Once you have the result set from the `findOne`, perform some validation on the `user` , avoid assuming it was found.
Also since Promise is now in ES6, you can use the built in Promise implementation

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Take note that a `findOne` returns a document, whereas doing a `find` always gives you an array of 0 or more document(s)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing

Comment: I need to use login function at a controller, so it really needs to return *something*, that's why I tried to return promise.

Even with last edits your answer is THE SAME I'm already doing

Comment: I agree after he added the return for clarity. @diegoaguilar You don't want the return in front of the FindOne call if you are calling then.

Comment: It's worth noting that in the example above, login is a **thenable** function. Everything returned from within "then" is a new promise.

Answer (score -2):

```js
login(email,password){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        Account.findOne({email: email}).then(function (user) {
            user.match = user.validPassword(password);
            resolve(user)
        });

    })
}
```

Comment: diegoaguilar, this should be working. What is the unwanted result? this is wrapped inside the login function correct?